# Update children's state in higher parent component

Tags: reactjs

I need some help. I have a wrapper `App` component where I hold the state of the application, the `App` component renders a `Router` component. I need to set in every page of the application the changes that were made on the page. Every page has a next button to the next page using `NavLink`s.

I tried to pass down a handle change method but I can not get it to work, the `handleChange` doesn't get fired. Any help would be very much appreciated.

App:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categoriesWithSub: [],
    currentPage: '',
    ticket: {
      departments: '',
      request: '',
      exactRequest: '',
      attachments: '',
    },
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const categories = await getCategories();

    const categoriesWithSub = await Promise.all(
      categories.map(async category => {
        const subCategories = await getSubCategories(category.id);
        return { ...category, subCategories };
      }),
    );
    this.setState({ categoriesWithSub });
  };

  makeHandleChange = () => {
    alert('Test!');
    /* this.setState({
      ticket: { ...this.state.ticket, [pageName]: pageChanges },
    }); */
  };

  render() {
    const { categoriesWithSub } = this.state;

    return <Router categoriesWithSub={categoriesWithSub} handleChange={this.makeHandleChange} />;
  }
}
```

Router:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/departments',
    exact: true,
    component: Departments,
  },
  {
    path: '/request',
    exact: true,
    component: Request,
  },
  {
    path: '/thank-you',
    exact: true,
    component: ThankYou,
  },
  {
    path: '/success',
    exact: true,
    component: Success,
  },
];

export default function Router(categoriesWithSub, handleChange) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {routes.map(({ path, exact, component: Component, layoutProps = {} }) => {
        const WithLayout = ({ ...props }) => (
          <Layout {...layoutProps}>
            <Component {...props} />
          </Layout>
        );
        return (
          <Route
            key={path}
            path={path}
            exact={exact}
            render={() => <WithLayout categoriesWithSub={categoriesWithSub} handleChange={handleChange} />}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Child component:

```
export default class extends Component {
  state = {
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.handleChange(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    const { categoriesWithSub } = this.props.categoriesWithSub;
    return (
        {categoriesWithSub &&
          categoriesWithSub.map(item => (
            <Tile
              to="./request"
              department={item.catName}
              key={item.id}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export function Tile({ to, department }) {
  return (
    <NavLink to={to} css={tile}>
      {department}
    </NavLink>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work

```
export default function Router(categoriesWithSub, handleChange)
```

That should be

```
export default function Router({categoriesWithSub, handleChange})
//or
export default function Router(props){
   const {categoriesWithSub, handleChange} = props;
}
```